# iPhone SDK SDL_openAudio with Multitasking Support

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, audio-streaming

I'm playing audio from a Online Live RTPS Stream with ffmpeg(because Apple doesn't support rtsp live streaming).

Now I would play my Stream in the background. I started a thread in the background and registered the music for Background support.

When the Application is entering in Background the NSThread is paused, and then Resuming after returning from background.

If I start playing a Music (MP3-Stream) in the Application which use official Apple Frameworks then when the App is entering Background both Streams are played.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like an audio session issue - did you play around with the session attributes? See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW1

Comment: Thank you, that was the Solution!

Comment: @Till Put your comment as answer. You have atleast +15 waiting ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, by popular demand ;), here comes the answer;

This very much sounds like an audio-session issue. You should try and fiddle a little with the session attributes: [AudioSessionProgrammingGuide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW1)